# Critique Request: CAD drafting contractor logo

Tags: logo, critique

I think I have convinced a client to allow me to redesign this logo as part of redesigning his website:

[image: The old logo]

A few pertinent pieces of input from my client:

- He *really* likes the grid layout in the background.
- He wants the "CAD" part of the name to stand out.
- ***UPDATE:*** I should also note that while my client does do some teaching, the primary service he offers is CAD Drafting as a consultant for engineers, architects, and manufacturers (basically anyone that requires a professional CAD drawing.)

So here's what I've come up with:

[image: The new logo]

I wanted to get some professional review before sending it off to my client. My main questions are:

1. Is the right face confusing? I was trying to communicate the idea of designing the cube in CAD (and add a grid in a way that didn't hurt my eyes.)
2. Does the font ([Poiret One](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Poiret+One)) match the style of the rest of the logo?

Thanks!

---

***UPDATE:*** Thanks to everyone for all the excellent suggestions; please don't hesitate to keep them coming if you have something else to add. I think the next step for me is to look at how to reduce the complexity (this probably means removing the client's beloved grid) and making sure the design scales properly. I'll update when I have a new version (or post a new question, if the next iteration is completely different).

---

***UPDATE 2:*** I've implemented some changes and posted the new version here. I would appreciate your feedback on the new versions if you have the time: [Is this logo redesign a step in the right direction or is it better to stick with the original?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/39417/23771)

Comment: THat right side will never hold up in print applications. It's too intricate.

Comment: Well… I think the name sounds bad. And the first C is too fat and the last D is too skinny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the logo. A couple of comments though:

I don't mind the **type**, the first half seems a little too round, but the CAD reminds me of the annotations on blueprints, which is (I think) a nice association. Perhaps you could investigate what other [blueprint fonts](http://blog.miragestudio7.com/architecture-fonts-download-free-architect-handwriting-font/3339/) there are out there that give the same feeling for the lowercase part as well.

What I would definitely look into is **the complexity of the logo**. How attached is your client to the grid? I think your **axis** element is much stronger than the grid, and it plays a similar role. A grid could be drawing paper, or a canvas, but the axis are definitely 3D, and anyone familiar with this sort of software will recognize this. I would try removing the grid from the cube, and reducing the cube's size. Less is more.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think the grid makes sense nor would fit the realm of print or embroidery..  When designing a logo you should think of every way possible that a logo can be viewed and you should consult the client what their intentions are in using their logo.  If the logo is just for a website it might do but ask yourself if that logo were to be used in the header that would be a large header.  If the logo was small I doubt anyone would pick-up on the grid detail if that logo were ever to be used for embroidery the grid will likely be denied by the company because it will be too fine of detail.

You should ask yourself does this logo define what the company name and views are..  If you dont know what the mention statement is of the company or what their goals are you will not and cannot make a logo dedicated to them.  When I  look at your font choice for me its out of place..  When I step back it doesnt make sense nor do I understand how a cube illustrates the phrase "compu" and "cad".

Answer (score 2):

CAD stands for Computer Aided Design.

As such, the company is essentially 'CompuComputer...'

Which is a little weird.

But the name is what it is, so I think your logo in an improvement.

The main concern with the old logo is that it's just very dated--namely the CAD typeface. It wouldn't resonate with any student today.

Things to think about with your logo:

- how's it going to look shrunk down?

  - is there too much detail?
  - do the lines need to be a bit heavier?
- Can the mark be simplified more?

  - do you need gradients, and arrows, and grids?
- Have you played with other type options?

  - try something heavier?

Comment: On a similar vein, people often say "ATM Machine", which makes the grammar nazi inside of me *cringe*. :)

Comment: See also: Chai Tea. :)

Comment: This surprisingly common. People also say SSD Drive. I mean back in the day when CAD still stood for Computer aided Drawing (yeah not anymore) people used to say CAD Drawing ;) So it seems to me people do this when the acronym would make the meaning little too thin. Rarely would you see people say SS Drive for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

this is essentially a long comment.

Please remember that someone using CAD/CAM/CAE systems most likely needs to be able to print the logo as apart of a manufacturing drawing. These frequently do not have the ability to print gradients and even color may be out of the question. So most likely your logo needs to be able to fit in the title area of such a drawing as well as other places. You can find some examples on their site.

Also try to fit the line weights in drawing titles it helps loads. I mean it would really appreciate if a designer would actually spend time understanding this and adjust accordingly. This is after all a CAD users letterhead. Most likely they also need a image free version of the text so it might need to stand on its own.

Other points:

- manufacturer might want to stamp the logo into products.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about your first point about it going on the drawing printouts. Would you mind clarifying the last paragraph? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Drawings are frequently done with uniform line widths (that is because the print may till today be plotted with a plotter), each reflecting different things. So if you can match your graphics so it works in conjunction with a few of these lines since most likely they are going to surround your logo and ruin your look and feel if you dont account for this.

Comment: The plotter is a good call...though, that said, I don't see plotters much at all anymore. Most everything is now done on large format ink-jet printers.

Comment: Which is a shame...as plotters were always fun to watch! :)

Comment: @DA01 watch a vinyl cutter, cnc mill or 3d printer instead. but yeah many archival bigscale prints are plotted sometimes because the needed quality is so high. And i have a plotter in my room. No driver for it tough.